# Jinja leave template tags after render

Tags: python, jinja2

The basic question of this topic is how to leave template tag if it is not define at context.
For example:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template('User {{Name}} have received {{count}} mails')
result = template.render({'count': 30})
```

In this case jinja will replace {{Name}} with '',
how make jinja leave {{Name}} in template instead of ''.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I founded a way to do that. Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67362301/15818639).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jinja2.Environment` constructor accepts `undefined` parameter, to control the behaviour in this case. By default it is [`jinja2.Undefined`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Undefined) which outputs nothing, but you could also use [`jinja2.DebugUndefined`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.DebugUndefined) or write your own implementation.

For example:

```
env = jinja2.Environment(undefined=jinja2.DebugUndefined)
t = env.from_string("{{foo}}{{bar}}")
t.render(foo=123)  # will print u'123{{ bar }}'
```

Comment: How make jinja leave {% for entry in entries %} in template when entiryes is not defined?

Comment: @cirfe I don't think there's out of the box solution, an explicit condition might be needed.

Comment: This works for me in case there is no comma between the brackets, like this:

>>> t = env.from_string("{{foo}}{{bar}}")
>>> t.render(foo=123)
u'123{{ bar }}'

But is printing "Undefined" if there is a comma, like this:

>>> t = env.from_string("{{foo,bar}}")
>>> t.render(foo=123)
u'(123, Undefined)'

What I want is to keep {{foo,bar}} as is. Any easy way to do this?

Comment: @user3477889 what do you want it to return?

Comment: @bereal I want to return {{foo,bar}}

Comment: @user3477889 I don't think it's possible by means of Jinja2.