# Keep undefined variables

Tags: python, jinja2, undefined

I am interested in rendering a template in multiple steps or keeping the tags for the undefined variables in Jinja2. I believe this would mean not only creating the 'UndefinedSilent" class (so the template won't crash on missing data) but also keeping the tags with the appropriate variable names if they are missing.

Example:
Let's say we have the **name = "Test"** included in the context, but **quantity** is missing.

Givent the following template:

```
<p>{{name}} has {{quantity}}</p>
```

After rendering, I need the template to become:

```
<p>test has {{quantity}}</p>
```

Does anyone know if this is achievable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Providing `DebugUndefined` to named parameter undefined in the env, apparently does the trick. The rendered template preserves the `{{<undefined variable}}`.

Like here:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader, DebugUndefined

rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader,undefined=DebugUndefined).from_string("{{ a }} is defined, but {{ b}} is undefined")
print(rtemplate.render({"a":"a"}))
```

The result is:

```
a is defined, but {{ b }} is undefined
```

Comment: If you use a different `variable_start_string` (or end, resp.), this doesn't work properly. Apparently the format `{{ <var> }}` is hard-coded here (have a look at `class DebugUndefined`) :-/

Comment: would you know how to make this work for multi level undefined variables? I can get the undefined to work properly for "{{ b }}" but not for "{{ b.c }}", that gives me the error jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'b' is undefined

Comment: I ended up just using my own variable start string, and variable end string which were different from "{{" and "}}". I used "{@". This works for my use case because I know beforehand which variables will be undefined, but I'd imagine that for use cases where it's not possible to know which variables will be undefined beforehand, it would still be nice to find a more versatile solution that was as convenient as the DebugUndefined but also worked for nested undefined variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is the version with `Template` rather than `Environment`:

```py
from jinja2 import Template, DebugUndefined

template = Template("<p>{{name}} has {{quantity}}</p>", undefined=DebugUndefined)

new_template = Template(template.render(name="Test"))
```

Thanks @giwyni

Another little hack if you just have few variables:

```py
<p>{{name}} has {{ "{{quantity}}" }}</p>
```

The second replacement will replace to `{{quantity}}` so all is good ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is achievable using the [*default* built-in filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters).

```
<p>{{name|default('{{name}}')}} has {{quantity|default('{{quantity}}')}}</p>
```

The drawback is that the code becomes uglier and the variable names are duplicated, thus reducing maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that preserves undefined double curly expressions after rendering, including those that contain "multilevel" (dot-notated) references as well as any others.

The answer provided by Willy Pregliasco does not support preservation of undefined list types, eg `{{ some_list[4] }}` which is something I required. The below solution addresses this, as well as all possible schema types.

The idea is to parse the input template and try to resolve each expression with the provided context. Any that can not be resolved, we replace with a double curly expression that simply resolves to the original expression as a string.

Pass your template and context through the below `preserve_undefineds_in_template` function before calling render:

```
from jinja2 import Template, StrictUndefined, UndefinedError
import re

def preserve_undefineds_in_template(template, context):
    patt = re.compile(r'(\{\{[^\{]*\}\})')
    j2_expressions = patt.findall(template)
    for j2_expression in set(j2_expressions):
        try:
            Template(j2_expression, undefined=StrictUndefined).render(context)
        except UndefinedError:
            template = template.replace(j2_expression, f"{{% raw %}}{j2_expression}{{% endraw %}}")
    return template
```

Example:

```
template = """hello {{ name }}, {{ preserve_me }} {{ preserve.me[2] }}"""

context = { "name": "Alice" }

# pass it through the preserver function
template = preserve_undefineds_in_template(template, context)

# template is now:
# hello {{ name }}, {% raw %}{{ preserve.me }}{% endraw %} {% raw %}{{ preserve.me.too[0] }}{% endraw %}

# render the new template as normal
result = Template(template).render(context)

print(result)
```

The output is:

```
hello Alice, {{ preserve_me }} {{ preserve.me[2] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wated the same behaviour. The library [jinja2schema](https://pypi.org/project/jinja2schema/) provides the schema of variables needed for your template.

The steps for my solution are:

- have a template
- obtain the schema structure
- give some data to fill
- complete de data filling the missing items with the original string

```py
from jinja2 import Template
import jinja2schema

def assign(schema, data, root=''):
    '''Returns a corrected data with untouched missing fields

    '''

    out = {}
    for key in schema.keys():

        if isinstance(schema[key], (str, jinja2schema.model.Scalar)): 
            try:
                out[key] = data[key]
            except:
                out[key] = f'{{{{ {root+key} }}}}'

        elif isinstance(schema[key], (dict, jinja2schema.model.Dictionary)):
            out[key]={}
            try:
                data[key]
            except:
                data[key] = {}
            out[key] = assign(schema[key], data[key], root+key+'.')

    return out

# original template
template_str = '<p>{{name}} has {{quantity}}</p>'
# read schema
schema = jinja2schema.infer(template_str)
# available data
data = {'name':'test'}
# data autocompleted
data_corrected = assign(schema, data)
# render
template = Template(template_str)
print(template.render(data_corrected))
```

The output is

```
<p>test has {{ quantity }}</p>
```

That was the intended result.

Hope it will help. This solution doesn't work with lists, but I think it is possible to extend the solution. You can also obtain the list of missing fields, if you need them.